# GO language: Reading a file and turning the content into an array

Tags: go

I want to implement this array in `main` function above but how?

`hosts := []string{"inanzzz1@100.79.154.22", "inanzzz2@200.79.190.11"}`

Content of JSON file:

```
inanzzz@inanzzz-VirtualBox:~/go$ go run reader.go < hosts.txt 
{
   {
      "username":"inanzzz1",
      "ip":"100.79.154.22"
   },
   {
      "username":"inanzzz2",
      "ip":"200.79.190.11"
   }
}
```

GO file which reads the JSON file above:

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    r := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    line, err := r.ReadString('\n')
    for i := 1; err == nil; i++ {
        //fmt.Printf("Line %d: %s", i, line)
        fmt.Printf(line)
        line, err = r.ReadString('\n')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that what you have is a json array (first and last {} replaced by []) instead of the invalid JSON described in hosts.txt here you have a working solution:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

type UsernameIp struct {
    Username string `json:"username"`
    Ip       string `json:"ip"`
}

func main() {
    j := json.NewDecoder(os.Stdin)
    var src []UsernameIp
    j.Decode(&src)

    var hosts []string
    for _, h := range src {
        entry := fmt.Sprintf("%s@%s", h.Username, h.Ip)
        hosts = append(hosts, entry)
    }

    fmt.Println(hosts)
}
```

Correct hosts.txt file:

```
[
   {
      "username":"inanzzz1",
      "ip":"100.79.154.22"
   },
   {
      "username":"inanzzz2",
      "ip":"200.79.190.11"
   }
]
```

Comment: When I run it with `go run json.go < hosts.txt ` I get `[]` as result

Comment: You need to have a valid JSON file. If you pass the file you suggested as an example in through a [linter](http://jsonlint.com) you will see it is not valid. A JSON array starts and ends with `[]`

Answer (score 1):

You probably should unmarshall json first and then iterate over result.
First - make hosts.txt a valid JSON. For that use `[]` instead of `{}`:

```
[
   {
      "username":"inanzzz1",
      "ip":"100.79.154.22"
   },
   {
      "username":"inanzzz2",
      "ip":"200.79.190.11"
   }
]
```

Then unmarshall.

Here is full example:

> package main
>
> import (
>           "fmt"
>           "encoding/json"
>      )
>
> func main() {
>
> ```
>   type host struct {
>    Username string 
>    Ip string  
> }
>
> cont := `    [
>    {
>       "username":"inanzzz1",
>       "ip":"100.79.154.22"
>    },
>    {
>       "username":"inanzzz2",
>       "ip":"200.79.190.11"
>    }
> ]
>  `
>
>
> // Read file to some byte array. We will use string for this example.
> var arr []host
> err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(cont), &arr) 
> if err != nil {   
>     fmt.Println(err)
> } 
>
> hosts := make([]string, len(arr))
> for i, h := range arr {
>    hosts[i] = h.Username + "@" + h.Ip
> } 
> fmt.Println(hosts)
> ```
>
> }

Comment: I'm trying to remove your hard coded JSON variable and implement "reading a txt file" feature instead. So how should I modify your code. I'm running it with `go run json.go < hosts.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ioutil.ReadFile](http://golang.org/src/pkg/io/ioutil/ioutil.go?s=1464:1510#L39) to read the whole file as a string which is a json document and then Unmarshal the string into a struct that you will have made for easy access:

```
type user_ip struct{
    username string `json:"username"`
    ip string       `json:"ip"`
}

type jsonStruct struct{
    sample []user_ip
}


func main() {

    //you'll have to read file here
    str := `{
               {
                  "username":"inanzzz1",
                  "ip":"100.79.154.22"
               },
               {
                  "username":"inanzzz2",
                  "ip":"200.79.190.11"
               }
            }`

    userIP := jsonStruct{}

    err := json.Unmarshal(str, &userIP)
    panic(err)

    //do what you want with the struct here
}
```